# Google Analytics API -> management_dailyUploads PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i just try upload my cost source data, with script:

```
require_once('Google/Client.php');
require_once('Google/Service/Analytics.php');
const ANALYTICS_SCOPE   = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics';
const CLIENT_ID             = 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_EMAIL         = 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
const KEY_FILE_PATH         = 'Google/keys/xxxx-privatekey.p12';
const VIEW_ID               = 'xxxx';
const accountId             = 'xxxx';
const webPropertyId         = 'UA-xxxx-1';
const customDataSourceId    = 'xxxx-wAyw';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName( 'Analytics' );
$client->setScopes( ANALYTICS_SCOPE );
$client->setClientId( CLIENT_ID );

$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_EMAIL,
        array( ANALYTICS_SCOPE ),
        file_get_contents( KEY_FILE_PATH )
        )
    );

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics( $client );

$results = $service->management_dailyUploads->upload(

    accountId,
    webPropertyId,
    customDataSourceId,
    date("Y-m-d"),
    1,
    'cost',
    array(
        "reset" => true,
        "data" => file_get_contents("csv/1239709550_sample.csv"),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
    )
);
print_r($results);
```

And i have a error:

```
"(403) User does not have permission to perform this operation."
```

https://www.google.com/analytics, "User Managment" have, user "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com" have a "Manage Users, Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze" permission.

https://code.google.com/apis/console, "Team" user "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com", have "Can edit" permission.

Comment: Make sure that you added that user at the "Account" level in Google Analytics admin, it wont work if you only added them at the View(profile) level.  you don't need to add them in the code.google.com/console.